# Remote MySQL: errno: -111, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 3306

Tags: mysql, deployment, server, connection, port

React beginner here. I just deployed an early-alpha of an app and currently getting this error -111 which from this [site](https://bobcares.com/blog/cant-connect-to-mysql-error-111-how-to-resolve/) says that its a problem that occurs when mysqld only listens to the localhost interface. I'm using a free remote mysql for testing from [this site](https://remotemysql.com/). It says that I have to find my.cnf and modify it to allow connections aside from localhost.

1. Will it work if I edit my my.cnf or no because I'm using a free remote mysql that I have no control of?
2. Will it work if I try another free remote mysql service that may work differently?

```js
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121413+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121421+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) 
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121421+00:00 app[web.1]: --------------------
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121422+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121422+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121423+00:00 app[web.1]: at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121423+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16) 
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121424+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121424+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/routes/operations/login.js:27:24
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121424+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121425+00:00 app[web.1]: at getInput (/app/routes/operations/login.js:20:16)
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121425+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/routes/operations/login.js:106:28
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121425+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121426+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121426+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121427+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121427+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121427+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121427+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2022-05-04T06:22:09.121428+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Comment: You need to change your code to point to the remote site's mysql server.   You're currently using localhost.   Please include the code.

Comment: @ewong i haven't written the code yet as I'm still skeptical of remote connections (even though It's all I have for the time being). I found a short tutorial about modifying the bind-address to allow remote connections here
(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql)

but was wondering if it will allow the remote site to have access to all my databases or only that one I got from them. the latter being what I want of course